# Cant add array to inside a array

Tags: php, arrays

Original:

```
$mesajData["msgBaslik"]="DEMO";
    $mesajData["msgData"][]=array(
        "tel"=>["5533038893","5544723385"],
        "msg"=>"Api Test"
    );
```

i want to add an array to inside "tel" index but not success yet.

Only success try:

```
$mesajData1["msgData"][]=array(
        "tel"=>[$to[0],$to[1]],
        "msg"=>"Api Test"
    );
```

But sometimes it has more than 100 values inside the array and cant do like that.

Comment: just continually push inside that particular index: `$mesajData['msgData'][0]['tel][] = 'whatever value this is';`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to |Ghost|

```
//$to -> Array with numbers
    $mesajData["msgBaslik"]="DEMO";
        $mesajData["msgData"][]=array(
            "tel"=>"",
            "msg"=>"Api Test"
        );
        for($x=0;$x<count($to);$x++){
            $mesajData['msgData'][0]['tel'][]="$to[$x]";
        }
```